# Should I create a Factless Fact Table or Denormalise my table

Tags: sql, dimensional-modeling

I am creating a data warehouse from a store database and I have a question regarding the design of my dimensions and facts.

In the store database a table exists for Person, Person_Address and Person_Address_Type. These are linked by another tabled name Entity_Address_ID which links the three tables by their primary keys to give details on what a person's address is and what type of address it is.

My question is, should I create a dimension for all three tables, and a fact-less fact table to link them together or should I de-normalise my dimensions and add to each dimension a foreign key for the address  and address type they are linked too?

Here is a very quick UML of what the current database looks like to provide clarification
[image: UML of Problem]

Comment: This seems more like a question for [dba.se] or maybe [programmers.se].

Comment: Is this due to its conceptual nature? I thought the Dimensional Modeling tag was appropriate maybe?

Comment: Pretty much. I don't think it's off-topic here; I just suspect you might get better answers at one of the other SE sites.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've also put it up on the DBA SE site, [link](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82527/should-i-create-a-factless-fact-table-or-denormalise-my-table)

Comment: Please don't cross post in the various stack exchange sites. In the future, you should flag to have the question moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a Person dimension with a set of address attributes (mailing address, billing address, etc), i.e. denormalize all this data and load it into a single table.

Comment: Can I ask why? is this best practice or your personal preference?
Considering this Database is actually the MSDN Sample Database Im thinking there must have been a reason for them to design the Database like this?

Comment: Yes that is correct, however correct me if im wrong but in dimensional modeling, Fact Tables are 3NF, but dims are 2NF?

Comment: Yes, but by 3NF model I only meant a non-dimensional model. I assumed that Person is only one of many dimensions in your warehouse. Is that correct? Do you have other dimensions and facts in the warehouse? Or do you need a dimensional model only for four tables from the question?

Comment: You are correct, there are many more dimensions and many more facts. This just happened to be the first one in the DW.

Comment: Going back to your first comment, is the MSDN sample a transactional database or a dimensional one?

Comment: Transactional, Its a stores sales/personnel database. [link](https://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/55330)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. The sample database is modeled in a way depicted on the screenshot, because normalization reduces redundancy and it is important in an OLTP system. If you want to copy the same data into a data warehouse, you don't worry about redundancy and performance becomes crucial, so the structure is denormalized or flattened. That's why I suggested a single dimension.